# Campos obrigatórios dependendo do formulário

Tags: ruby-on-rails

preciso especificar o que vai ser obrigatório dependendo de qual formulário é exibido.

tenho um Modelo que possui alguns campos Ex.:

//Model User

:nome, :idade, :endereco

No Create para o User, somente :nome deve ser obrigatório. Depois que o User for criado, vai ter dois links um abrirá um formulário em um modal solicitando somente a :idade, e nesse formulário a :idade deve ser obrigatório. E no outro link abrirá também um formulário em um modal solicitando somente o :endereco que por sua vez também deve ser obrigatório nesse formulário.

Como seria a melhor forma de isso ser possível?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a melhor forma de fazer isso é validando com JS(Javascript), utilizando a tag Required=true no HTML e colocando um

> validates :nome, :idade, :endereço presence: true

no Model

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar métodos condicionais no seu model e trata as validações condicionais:

```
validates :campo, presence: true, if: campoo_obrigatorio?

def campo_obirgatorio?
 // retorno booleano
end
```

Answer (score -3):

Não cheguei a testar, mas não funciona assim?

1. Colocar todos os campos como requeridos
2. Em cada action do controller remover os métodos que não deseja

   ```
   def create
     if params[:user][:idade].blank?
       params[:user].delete(:idade)
     end

     if params[:user][:endereco].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:endereco)
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/99457)

Comment: Ok! Anotado! Apesar da resposta estar correta fui negativado :-)

Comment: Como sabe que a resposta está correta, se você não chegou a testar?